# counting text node recursively using javascript

Tags: javascript, textnode

Let say I have a mark up like this

```
<html id="test">
<body>
Some text node.
<div class="cool"><span class="try">This is another text node.</span></div>
Yet another test node.
</body>
</html>
```

my js code

```
function countText(node){
 var counter = 0;
 if(node.nodeType === 3){
     counter+=node.nodeValue.length;
     countText(node);
 }
 else{}
}
```

Now if I want to count the text nodes

```
console.log("count text : " + countText(document.getElementById("test"));
```

this should return me the count but its not working and moreover what should I put in else condition.
I never used nodeType so kind of having problem using it . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that given the same HTML, different browsers may create different numbers of text nodes.

Comment: @RobG can you explain it briefly about the behavior...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code:

- Your HTML is malformed.
- You are appending text to your `counter` instead of increasing it.
- You never loop over the children of the a node, you always pass the same node to the recursive call.
- You don't do anything if a node is not a text node.

This will work:

```
function countText(node){
    var counter = 0;
    if(node.nodeType === 3){
        counter++;
    }
    else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // if it is an element node, 
       var children = node.childNodes;    // examine the children
       for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
          counter += countText(children[i]);
       }
    }
    return counter;  
}

alert(countText(document.body));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/rYzUK/)

Which number corresponds to which node type [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).

---

**Update:**

If you want to count the **words**, you have to split each text node into words first. In the following I assume that words are separated by white spaces:

```
if(node.nodeType === 3){
    counter = node.nodeValue.split(/\s+/g).length;
}
```

**Update 2**

I know you want to use a recursive function, but if you want to count the words only, then there is a much easier and more efficient way:

```
function countWords(node){
    // gets the text of the node and all its descendants
    var text = node.innerText || node.textContent
    return text.split(/\s+/g).length;
}
```

Comment: It's not really necessary to bother testing for any other node type.  If it's a text node, count it.  Then in any case, iterate over all children if any exist.

Comment: @Felix I am not worried about the markup...but your function counts 3 whereas there are 12 text counts .....so I think have to use node.value.length instead of counter but your else statement make sense since elements most common nodeType

Comment: @user429035: Ah, so you want to count the words? That is different than counting the text nodes. In your example above, there are 3 text nodes. You should have made this clear (and my script counts 3, not 2 text nodes). Please see my update. Btw valid markup is important, as only then you can know whether your script will work or not. E.g. in your HTML you are missing a closing quotation mark `<span class="try>` which has the consequences that the browser does not render the remaining markup.

Comment: +1 @Felix...sorry for the confusion....Yes that was a mistake class="try" missed double quotes...

Comment: @user429035: No worries :) Please see also my second update. There is a much more efficient way than using recursion... but whatever you want of course ;)

Comment: @Felix thanks! but still I have one more confusion ...when you use the id of <html id="test">  it gives me a different result ...any idea  on that?

Comment: @Felix it gives me 16 whereas actual count is 12 ...any idea ?

Comment: @user429035: Well, I assume it counts something which is in the `head` of the page. There is no reason to the select the `html` element anyway. All the visible content (i.e. the content that matters) is inside the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
function countTextNodes(node) {
    var n = 0;
    if(node.nodeType == 3)
        n = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i)
        n += countTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
    return n;
}
```

This can be compressed into more compact code, but I went for legibility here.

Call this on the root in which you want to count text nodes.  For example, to count text nodes throughout the entire document, you would want to call `countTextNodes(document.getDocumentElement())`.

Comment: @chomp thanks! but I don't want to use for loop instead just want to do it recursively ...and is Type valid because I think its nodeType..

Comment: @user429035: It is still recursive. You have to use a for loop, otherwise, how do you want to call the function on the child nodes? You have to iterate over the children.

Comment: Do note that the loop only iterates over the immediate children, recursively calling `countTextNodes` on each of them and accumulating the results.  As @Felix Kling suggests, you will find it impossible to accomplish your goal without such iteration.  Also, you are correct about `nodeType`.  Sorry about the typo!

Comment: @chomp and @Felix agree... I have to use the for loop in else statement as @Felix suggested which makes sense

Comment: Ok, but you don't need the `else`.

Comment: @user429035: @chomp is right, it is not really necessary, but it doesn't hurt and might make the intention clearer (e.g. we don't want to examine comment nodes (which would not be a problem though as they would just be ignored)).

Comment: @chomp you are right not necessary but it will just make things clearer ....@Felix thanks

Comment: please use `=== Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of the magic number `3`